# Error while running expect in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, expect, aix

Getting error while running expect script in bash script

Input:

```
{

    /usr/bin/expect << EOF

    spawn ssh execsped@10.150.10.194  "cd /home/execsped/ram_test_72;./testecho.sh \"$evenno\" \"$eisinno\" \"$efilename\""

    expect "Password"

    send "abc@123\r"

    expect "*#*"

EOF

}
```

Output:

```
extra characters after close-quote

    while executing

"spawn ssh execsped@10.150.10.72 "cd /home/execsped/evoting_test_72;./testecho.sh "10575" "_eVoting.pdf" "abc.pdf"
"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the escaped quotes. look at the final command it's trying to run: `"cd /home/execsped/evoting_test_72;./testecho.sh "10575" "_eVoting.pdf" "abc.pdf" "` it should run fine without the escaped quotes.

Comment: still getting error

extra characters after close-quote
    while executing
"spawn ssh execsped@10.150.10.194 "cd /home/execsped/evoting_test_72;./testecho.sh "10575" "_eVoting.pdf" "abc.pdf""
"

Comment: no, i meant run it like: `spawn ssh execsped@10.150.10.194  "cd /home/execsped/ram_test_72;./testecho.sh $evenno $eisinno $efilename"`